# How the unix sed sort combine use with ruby format looks like?

Tags: ruby, bash, unix, streaming, stdin

*the purpose of using sed because i want to read it line by line streaming.

I have few questions about unix bash and ruby, I am really confused about the syntax of bash.If someone can offer me some examples, it really helps people to learn. Appreciate every responses.

1.let say I want to read in a server.txt on the command line, and then sort it by the server contents aplhabetically

here is how server.txt looks like

> pacific
>   asia
>   northamerica
>   america

Here what I typed

```
sed -e server.txt |sort| > done.txt
```

but it seems not working well, how to fix it?

2.And my second question is how to I combine the use of unix command and ruby script.
  like i want to stream in a file and then input line by line input to my ruby file. and then output to some files.
 I tried

```
sed -e server.txt ruby filter.rb > done.txt
```

this doesn't work too.

3.what is $stdin $stdout mean?

4.if server.txt is like 10gb which doesn't fit in memory, can we still use sort? or sort is like automatically doing the streaming and merging for us?

Comment: in this case,it just bunch of location names followed by end of line at each line.

Comment: because i want to speed up the stdin and stdout, i guess this is one of good way to do it?

Comment: @runcode sed is more for editing. If I understand you correctly you just want to do this: sort server.txt > done.txt

Comment: sed is a stream editor, it doesn't speed up anything. If you want to sort your server.txt file, just do `sort server.txt >done.txt`.

Comment: if server.txt is like 10gb which doesn't fit in memory,  can we still use sort? or sort is like automatically doing the streaming and merging for us?

Comment: `sort` will automatically spill intermediate files to disk so that it can sort files bigger than memory (but it needs enough disk space — for such a big file, it might need two intermediate copies plus the original).

Comment: the point i use sed because i want to skip the 1000 records, like sed 1000d server.txt |sort| ruby filter.rb > result.txt , so if give up on sed, how do i acheive this goal? PLS HELP . THANKS!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If what you typed is precisely:

   ```
   sed -e server.txt |sort| > done.txt
   ```

   you should be getting a syntax error from `sed` complaining that the third 'e' is missing from 'server.txt' (because it will treat that as an attempt at formulating a substitute command with 'e' as the expression delimiter; the `-e` option means the following argument is a command expression, not a file name).

   The second pipe should be omitted.  As written, you've invoked a null command that creates a file `done.txt` and then does nothing.  If you wanted the output written to the file, you'd need to put a `cat` or `tee` command in there.  Or, better, omit the second pipe so that `sort` writes to the file.

   > Can you give an example of how to use `cat` or `tee` to make first example work?

   ```
   sed -e s/a/b/g server.txt | sort | cat > done.txt  # UUOC award
   sed -e s/a/b/g server.txt | sort | tee   done.txt
   sed -e s/a/b/g server.txt | sort       > done.txt  # No UUOC award
   sed -e s/a/b/g server.txt | sort      -o done.txt  # No UUOC award
   ```

   I've added an expression for `sed` so it will read the file `server.txt`.  [UUOC](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html) is the 'Useless Use of Cat' award.  There's absolutely no need to use `cat` in the example.  Using `tee` might make sense if you're planning to read all 10 GiB of data as it scrolls past; otherwise, one of the last two options is more sensible; they're essentially equivalent in this context.
2. Your second command:

   ```
   sed -e server.txt ruby filter.rb > done.txt
   ```

   should be written as:

   ```
   sed -e s/a/b/g server.txt | ruby filter.rb > done.txt
   ```

   I've provided a silly action for the `-e` option to `sed`; the output of `sed` is piped to the `ruby` script, and the output is then written to `done.txt`.  This is a very standard sort of idiom.
3. Without more context, I can't tell you what `$stdin` and `$stdout` mean.  In different languages, it means slightly different things, but typically would be a reference to a variable of some sort.  I'm not sure whether any languages treat those two names as special; probably there are some, but neither Perl nor shell has a special meaning for those names.

Comment: can you give an example that  how i use the cat or tee to make first example work? for the #2, what is s/a/b/g doing? is that sed must take 2 arguments? thankyou!

Comment: one more question ,from my understanding, i think s/a/b/g means substitue every a by b globally, so in my case i dont want to do subsitution, what do i put there?

Comment: If you don't want to do any substitutions or other editing, then you won't use `sed` at all; you'd tell `sort` to sort the file: `sort -o done.txt server.txt` or `ruby filter.rb server.txt | sort -o done.txt` or any of a large number of possible variants.  Don't use a command like `sed` unless you're going to use its functionality, especially on monster (multi-gigabyte) files.

Comment: oh, the point i use sed because i want to skip the 1000 records, like sed 1000d server.txt |sort| ruby filter.rb > result.txt , so if give up on sed, how do i acheive this goal?